# Oracle Database: May I drop a datafile created by mistake?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to get rid off a data file which created mistakenly, the db is Oracle 10g R2. May I do the following?

```
alter tablespace abc drop datafile '/abc.dbf'
```

The data file abc.dbf is in offline (needs recovery) state and 0 byte. Since it is offlined, I think it can't be dropped this way, so what's your suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/oracle-database-what-can-i-do-to-drop-a-data-file-mistakenly-created-and-current

Comment: surprisingly, it's the same user who posted that question, wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to bring it back online first, then drop.

```
alter database abc datafile '/abc.dbf' online;
```

you'll get an ORA error saying that the file needs recovery, do that

```
recover datafile '/abc.dbf';
```

bring it online and drop it then

```
alter tablespace abc drop datafile '/abc.dbf';
```

If that doesn't work for you, do either of:

- export tablespace objects of interest, drop the whole tablespace, create it again and import the exported file
- create a new tablespace, copy objects, recreate indexes and drop the old tablespace

Note: if you go with dropping the tablespace, don't forget to also specify to drop the datafiles with it.

```
drop tablespace abc including contents and datafiles;
```

Comment: thx much, makes lot sense! I have never did recover datafile '/abc.dbf'; is that safe to do? since our prod db has no backup now...

Comment: forgot to mention we don't have backup because this data file in offline and in needs recovery state...

Comment: yes, `recover datafile` is safe to do for the rest of the DB, but my point was that i'm not so sure the recovery will succeed, that's why i wrote you an alternative.

Comment: me too, I am waiting on my boss to give me the green light, but since we don't have backup currently so I think my boss is extra causious...

Comment: Well, he's totally right. Back it up already dude! And by the way, just last week I had to do something similar to one DB without backup, so what I did to save time, was to backup the whole hard drive (in fact I took a snapshot of the virtual machine, as it was running on a blade server) and restored it after the DB was actually screwed:D

Comment: my boss adviced to go to the safe way to move data off the table space then drop the tablespace along with all the data files... so will not find out if the other way would work at this point, thanks anyway, will keep you posted in the future if I have a chance to try the alternative way to drop a data file

Comment: Cool. I was somehow expecting your news today, probably figured out that you only work on tuesdays:) Good luck with Oracle!

Comment: hi, today I tried to drop the whole tablespace including the data files, but got an error, as ORA-01156: recovery in progress may need to access files; since that troubled data file is in need recovery mode even it is offline and 0 bite, so I should do alter tablespace abc drop datafile '/abc.dbf'; first right?

Comment: Update, not be able to drop the data files when dropping the tablespace, and recover the data file won't work either since  needs all the archive logs which is too late now (a month later), so the solution is to drop the table space with its contents (but not data files), then delete those data files from os level (Linux deletion command), then it worked perfectly...